# Is it semantic to use <form> tag when even there is no submission?

Tags: html, forms, semantic-markup

I wonder about semantics of `<form>` tag.

### Few inputs

In my React application I have some checkbox inputs that filter the displayed data:

```html
<input type="checkbox" name="filter-a" />
<input type="checkbox" name="filter-b" />
<input type="checkbox" name="filter-c" />
```

It's done:

- Without a submit button - filtering logic is triggered on toggling each checkbox
- No request to the server is made - the whole filtering logic is done in the browser's JavaScript

### Question

Is it recommended/valid to wrap those inputs in a `<form>` element?

```html
<form>
  <input type="checkbox" name="filter-a" />
  <input type="checkbox" name="filter-b" />
  <input type="checkbox" name="filter-c" />
</form>
```

I'm not asking about the functionality (it works without it), but about the semantics.

### Doubts

I have my doubts, because this form does not make any submission nor makes any request. [MDN documentation on `<form>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/form) says:

> The  HTML element represents a document section containing interactive controls for **submitting** information.

I can still see how I can treat firing form logic on each checkbox toggle as submission. I just wonder what the official semantics and guidelines are.

Comment: If you do not need the semantic markup the form gives, and do not need the HTML5 validation a submit will trigger then I would say no, you do not need a form tag

Comment: @mplungjan What do you mean by "semantic markup the form gives"?

Comment: Screen readers might interpret the checkboxes differently if they are wrapped in a form tag, ditto tabbing might be influenced

Comment: @mplungjan do you have experience of that happening, or is that speculation?

Comment: Speculation. Which this question sort of begs

Comment: @mplungjan What do you think is wrong with this question? I ask because I'd really like to know how to ask this question in a proper way. I want to write semantic and accessible markup and couldn't find clear information on this anywhere.

Comment: @mplungjan It's important to be clear on that. In my experience screen readers interpret and tab to interactive elements the same way regardless of if they're in a form or not.

Comment: I would expect someone to vote to close this question as "asks for opinions" but I understand where you come from. I would personally not bother with the form tag unless a test with a screen reader showed me it mattered